# How should I create the bootable media to install a 64-bit Windows 7 Home Basic edition?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, bootable-media

I have obtained my Microsoft Windows 7 Product Key, and I have decided to do a fresh install the Windows 7 Home Edition.

**How should I create the bootable media to install a 64-bit Windows 7 Home Basic edition?**

I was redirected by Microsoft support representative to
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7, but he himself said that this link is for retail key, and my key is not retail key but rather one shipped with the machine (OEM key?).

My question is actually in extension with the question posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft).[image]

I have to Create this new thread for the 2 reason →

1. I do not have 50 reputation yet to ask question in comment box there.
2. I have lots of questions that thread was unable to answer.

That thread gives a link → http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/
I could Not find Window 7 Home Basic Download link for 64 bit window. Can some one Please help me with that?

I found this →
en_windows_7_home_basic_with_sp1_x86_dvd_u_676470.iso

But I am not sure if it is equivalent to 64 bit installation also.

If my above question is resolved then my 2nd question will be → Since the download link is .iso extension so just by saving it in dvd will it be a bootable window or we have to still burn it to create a DVD?

I have  4.7GB DVD and I hope that will be sufficient.

Comment: @Champion [This](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) provides detailed steps to download what you want.  Follow the directions.

Comment: I just read that and I am unable to understand your javascript part. should I copy paste some code in console? You have mentioned there → You can then proceed to use the same script as before. which script sir? I need to put this code in my console? https://jsfiddle.net/Lwcjhshu/

Comment: The script in my answer.  As this discussion is getting ridiculous, going to delete my comments, because my answer is detailed and complete

Comment: @Champion - I thought I had updated the answer, when I discovered the user agent had to be changed, I guess I forgot to actually submit the edit back in November.  *I have confirmed, as recently as 2 minutes ago, my answer as currently written is correct.*

Comment: Thanks, but I can see that the steps are same what should I do not to download window 7 home basic 64 bit. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: what do means by this → be sure to change the user agent to something that isn't a Windows browser? I am using Mozilla. Do I need something else? Are you saying i should not even use the window machine(computer)?

Comment: **Exactly** what it says, you can't select Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or IE, pick a browser that doesn't run on Windows.

Comment: It does not appear Windows 7 Home Basic even has a 64-bit ISO.

Comment: Means home basic doesn't exist with the 64 bit?

Comment: @Champion - You can only download 32-bit versions of `Windows 7 Home Basic` and `Windows 7 Starter` 64-bit versions of those two editions do not exist.

Comment: It looks like I wasted my whole 1 week. I have one earnest request to you. i will be indebted to you if you give me 2 minutes. I have run a Intel Utility, and here is the Outcome can you please check if my system is at all compatible to 64 bit? →  [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/projectsts/Think+Centre/intel+utility+test.txt) also this one → [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/projectsts/Think+Centre/Window_os_7_32bit-2.png)

Comment: @Champion [Yes](http://ark.intel.com/products/53426/Intel-Core-i3-2120-Processor-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz).  You just can't run a 64-bit guest operating system within a virtual machine with the hardware you have.  Your motherboard does not support enabling the virtualization technology x86 extension (VT-x).

Comment: So I wont be able to run any 64 bit operating system not even window 10 64 bit?

Comment: @Champion - I didn't say that.  You asked if you can run a 64-bit operating system, my answer to that question was, **Yes**.  I then explained that the only thing you CANNOT do is run a 64-bit operating system within a virtual machine due to your hardware not allowing to enable the virtualization technology (vt-x) your CPU supports.  Please read the entire comment, it is very clear, absolutely no chance it taken as a statement your hardware does not support 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: Please pardon me and dont feel irritated I am not tech savvy like you. Do I have to change motherboard? or formatting can do that? I have run one more utility → [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/yVIKDrWdSJM) ; I did this after reading this article → [link](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-will-your-pc-run-it/)

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.  Your CPU supports 64-bit versions of Windows 7.  Your CPU will run Windows 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53445/discussion-between-ramhound-and-champion).